# Is the word "else" used correcly here?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

You get approximately 5-6 questions in this task; for which it is advised that you spend 2 minutes per question. As there is no negative marking, choose the answer if you are confident **else** you can let go the question.

Comment: I don't think so. I'd accept ***otherwise*** there, but ***else*** should be preceded by ***or***. And probably most people would include a comma between the two alternatives (i.e. - after ***confident***). I'm not happy about *you can let go the question* either (at least include the preposition ***of*** after ***let go*** there, but I'm not keep on that particular usage here anyway).

Comment: You can use 'else' like 'otherwise' in conversation in some British regional dialects, e.g. 'wear a coat else you'll get wet', but it is not standard, and 'let go the question' is not standard either. I don't think that text was written by a native English speaker.

Comment: `if`... `else` is a computer language construct.

Comment: It should probably be "skip [over]" instead of "let go". +1 on "otherwise".